# LiveCharts2 with WPF & MVVM: How to bind a dynamically calculated property to a chart series?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, livecharts

**Adhering to the MVVM pattern, how do I bind a chart to dynamically calculated property data and make the chart reflect changes?**

I'm working on a GUI application where certain parameters are adjustable via controls and the function values of a computational model dependent on these parameters should be plotted in real time when any parameters are adjusted.

I'm programming in C# using WPF and want/need to use the MVVM pattern, which I have only recently learned (I'm also relatively new to C#). I chose [LiveCharts2](https://lvcharts.com) for plotting because it can be used with the MVVM pattern; a different library that does the job (X-Y-diagrams that automatically update based on data binding) would be fine, too.

The following code is a simplification of my actual application, which is much more complex. The model is a simple parabola function `y=a*x²` where `a` is the parameter that is adjusted via a `TextBox` in the GUI. When adjusted, the parabola function should be updated in the diagram.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestLvc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestLvc"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Name="DrawingGrid" Width="400" Height="400">
                <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding DataPointCalculator.SeriesBindable}" />
            </Grid>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DataPointCalculator.ParabolaFactor}" Width="30" />
            <Button>Lose Focus from TextBox in order to update binding</Button>
            <Label Name="LabelBoundValue" Content="{Binding DataPointCalculator.ParabolaFactor}" />
            <Label Content="^- Bound value" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Notes:

- The button doesn't do anything on its own, it just makes the `TextBox` lose focus and thereby apply the input value.
- The `Label` below the button has the same binding as the `TextBox` in order to validate that the binding is working.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
// Choose one:

#define use_dependent_property // Preferred solution: Doesn't work.

#define recalculate_points_in_setter // Works.

#define recalculate_property_in_setter // Should be similar to recalculate_points_in_setter and therefore working, but doesn't.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.Defaults;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;

namespace TestLvc;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainViewModel vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DataPointCalculator = new ParabolaCalculator(5);
    }

    public ParabolaCalculator DataPointCalculator { get; set; }
}

public class ParabolaCalculator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly double[] XValues =
        Enumerable.Range(-20, 41).Select(stepIndex => (double) stepIndex * 1).ToArray();

    private double _parabolaFactor;

    public ParabolaCalculator(double parabolaFactor = 1)
    {
        ParabolaFactor = parabolaFactor;

#if use_dependent_property
        LineSeriesSeries.Values = DataPointsDependent;
#elif recalculate_points_in_setter
        LineSeriesSeries.Values = DataPointsCalculated;
#elif recalculate_property_in_setter
        LineSeriesSeries.Values = DataPointsCalculated;
#endif

        SeriesBindable = new List<ISeries> {LineSeriesSeries};
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ObservablePoint> DataPointsCalculated { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ObservablePoint> DataPointsDependent => CalculateDataPoints();

    public List<ISeries> SeriesBindable { get; set; }

    public LineSeries<ObservablePoint> LineSeriesSeries { get; set; } = new();

    public double ParabolaFactor
    {
        get => _parabolaFactor;
        set
        {
            _parabolaFactor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ParabolaFactor));

#if use_dependent_property
            // Don't do calculations manually, because the data points are dynamically calculated -- but how is the chart informed that the underlying parameter has changed?
            // Raising property-changed events doesn't help.
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SeriesBindable));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataPointsDependent));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LineSeriesSeries));
#elif recalculate_points_in_setter
            RecalculateDataPoints();
#elif recalculate_property_in_setter
            DataPointsCalculated = CalculateDataPoints();
#endif
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void RecalculateDataPoints()
    {
        DataPointsCalculated ??= CalculateDataPoints();
        foreach (var point in DataPointsCalculated) point.Y = ParabolaFunction((double) point.X);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ObservablePoint> CalculateDataPoints()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ObservablePoint> points = new();
        foreach (var x in XValues) points.Add(new ObservablePoint(x, ParabolaFunction(x)));
        return points;
    }

    private double ParabolaFunction(double x)
    {
        return ParabolaFactor * (x * x);
    }
}
```

I included three compiler constants that lead to different implementations:

`use_dependent_property` would be the way I want it to work: The model data depends on the parameter value, so it makes sense to implement the model data as the dependent property `DataPointsDependent`. The chart data can be bound to this property, but the chart is not updated when the parameter is changed. **How can this be achieved?**

`recalculate_points_in_setter`: Here, the chart is bound to the property `DataPointsCalculated` which is a `ObservableCollection<ObservablePoint>` and whose `ObservablePoint`s are updated in the parameter's setter. This works and would be OK for a simple case like this, but considering a larger number of parameters and a more complex view model, it does not seem like an option to me. It also looks to me like this solution works around the MVVM pattern, because with MVVM and data binding, you should not have to deal with manual updates, should you?

`recalculate_property_in_setter`: Bonus question. The chart is again bound to `ObservableCollection<ObservablePoint> DataPointsCalculated` and the model data are updated in the parameter's setter, but here the whole `DataPointsCalculated` is replaced instead of it's `ObservablePoint`s. Given that the second approach works, why won't this one work? Based on [the documentation on automatic updating](https://lvcharts.com/docs/wpf/2.0.0-beta.300/Overview.Automatic%20updates), I think it should, because:

> // since valuesCollection is of type ObservableCollection
> // LiveCharts will update when you add, remove, **replace** or clear the collection
> var valuesCollection = new ObservableCollection();
> var lineSeries = new LineSeries();
> lineSeries.Values = valuesCollection;

Note on LiveCharts2: This is still a pre-release, but I tried the same with [LiveCharts0](https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts) with the same outcome.